# Disqus - change this.page.identifier but keep all comments

Tags: javascript, disqus

I have a Disqus app embedded on my site and I use `this.page.identifier = "123";` in my JavaScript. I need to change the "123" to "abc", and I need keep all comments of the thread. Is there a way to do it? If I change `this.page.identifier = "123"` to `this.page.identifier = "abc"`, the existing comments will no longer be displayed.

Comment: ***why*** are looking to change it in the first place?

Comment: Because the identifier is a string which contains a private info (UUID) which cannot be shown to normal visitors. If somebody type a special URL with UUID as param into his browser, he can break app.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be possible using the https://disqus.com/api/3.0/threads/update.json API endpoint ([documentation](https://disqus.com/api/docs/threads/update/)). As of this writing, the endpoint is still in beta.

Using the API endpoint, you can supply `old_identifier` and `identifier`. The former is the identifier you want to change, and the latter is the new value you want to change the old identifier to.

Should you happen to be interested, I have asked a follow-up question about deleting all identifiers of a thread (instead of just changing the identifiers): [How do I remove all identifiers from a Disqus thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66867492)