# How do I remove all identifiers from a Disqus thread?

Tags: disqus

Each Disqus thread can have one or more [identifiers](https://help.disqus.com/en/articles/1717082-what-is-a-disqus-identifier) (usually one initially supplied by `this.page.identifier` in the [JavaScript embed code](https://help.disqus.com/en/articles/1717112-universal-embed-code) of webpage). The list of identifiers for a thread can be obtained from the [threads/details](https://disqus.com/api/3.0/threads/details.json) API endpoint ([documentation](https://disqus.com/api/docs/threads/details/)). Example response:

```json
{
  "code":0,
  "response":{
    ...
    "identifiers":[
      "my-identifier",
      "my-other-merged-identifier"
    ],
    ...
  }
}
```

Is there a way to delete/remove all identifiers from a thread? I would like the thread/details API endpoint to end up with this response:

```json
{
  "code":0,
  "response":{
    ...
    "identifiers":[],
    ...
  }
}
```

I am also open to a solution that does this through the web interface (if possible at all).